# Column selection in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a condition on a data frame based on a column which is boolean. that column is called romantic .

```
Engaged = df ["Romantic"] == "True"

df [Engaged]
```

it returns nothing.

any suggestion?

the dataset is here

https://data.world/data-society/student-alcohol-consumption

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframe? Is it a string "True" or an actual python Boolean True?

Comment: Welcome to SO - please provide a minimal example of the DataFrame or column - please read [mre].

Comment: not its embeded in an excel file which romantic is one of the columns and the cells are as true or false

Comment: I just added the data set

Answer (score 1):

You can using boolean indexing with your boolean datatype pd.Series from your dataframe column.

MVCE:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'color':[*'rbgyb'], 'value':[True, False, True, True, False]})

df[df['value']]
```

Output:

```
  color  value
0     r   True
2     g   True
3     y   True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Engaged = df[df["Romantic"] == True]
print(Engaged)
```